# iptables rules for postgresql remote connection

Tags: iptables, postgresql

I have this rule on my iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5432 -s 123.45.67.89 -j ACCEPT
```

where 123.45.67.89 is the client ip that i want to connect to my db server.
can you please tell me what's the problem? this still won't allow me to connect. When i try to stop my firewall or flush the rules, i can be able to remotely connect to postgresql.

Please help. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a rule for keeping state?
For example '-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT'

Do you connect to the server over the eth0 interface?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a rule above this one that drops that kind of packets. Please check it or show full iptables ruleset.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. I;ve fixed it via '-I' instead of '-A' . It seems that the order of rules in iptables matter.

Hope this will help somebody in the future.